# Current time is not valid according to timezone

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

Using below code in `php` to get current time:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Toronto");
echo date('y-m-d H:i:s', time());
```

But, there is a time difference of 3 minutes and 30 seconds with real time.

Comment: check that on the box where you run this code, that you are running some form of NTP protocol and that it is synced to an appropriate source.

Comment: What is NTP protocol and how to check this? The server is running on Azure. (Ubuntu OS)

Comment: 3 min 30 sec difference is not a timezone issue, it's a clock drift issue. See [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254826/how-to-force-a-clock-update-using-ntp).

Comment: NTP : network time protocol, used to sync boxes to well known time references, **[see here on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)**.

Answer (score 0):

3 minutes and 30 seconds is not enough to be a timezone issue. No active timezone is shifted only by 210 seconds.

The issue is probably caused by either your server or your local machine being out of sync. Have you checked that your local machine actually matches the current time? Check for example third-party services such as [Google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=current%20time) to determine if it is your server or local machine that is out of sync.

If it is your local machine, the solution depends on your system. If it is your server, it can be updated with `timedatectl --adjust-system-clock`.